# PDO dont work when trying to execute INSERT command

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i'm trying to INSERT a sql query but it does not work - I got no errors, `$pdo->errorInfo();` only returns `Array` and in the mysql is nothing to see!
Im 100% sure that $text, $file and $title is set (i've check that with `echo`) In every other php file this pdo connection works with `include` but not in the **dev.php** what should i do???

**datenbank.php**

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', 'user', 'password');
?>
```

**dev.php**

```
include("datenbank.php");
// Prepare an insert statement
$post = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO news (text, date, file, title) VALUES ($text, NOW(), $file, $title)");
$post->execute(); 
$help = $pdo->errorInfo();
```

Comment: You need to go read up on some MySQL syntax basics. You are using several unquoted keywords as column names here, and what are presumably string values without proper quoting as well. _“$pdo->errorInfo(); only returns Array”_ - did you try to output it using `echo` perhaps? Use var_dump or print_r.

Comment: @misorude now errprInfo(); returns '1' :/ and i know that this column names not the best, but this just for me so i dont care about the names i just care about that it works :3

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php have a look at the syntax of PDO prepare here for some examples

Comment: _“and i know that this column names not the best, but this just for me so i dont care about the names”_ - but the database cares. So please go read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html first of all.

Answer (score 1):

You don't use the parameters markers in your `prepare` PDO stament. When you prepare a query using PDO extension, you need put markers in your query statement and indicate the value of those markers in the `execute` function like an associative array.

You can use markers like `:marker` or question marks `?` and your query would be like that:

```
include("datenbank.php");
// Prepare an insert statement with marks params
$post = $pdo->prepare(INSERT INTO news (text, date, file, title) VALUES (:text, NOW(), :file, :title));
//execute statements with the marks values in prapare function params
$post->execute(array(':text' => $text, ':file' => $file, ':title' => $title));
```

Edit: PD: This prevents the SQL inyection.......

Answer (score 0):

for string value you need  quote

```
$post = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO news (text, date, file, title) 
   VALUES ('$text', NOW(),'$file', '$title')");
```

anyway you should not use  php var in sql , you are at risk for sqlinjection  .. use prepared statements and binding param instead

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO news (text, date, file, title) 
         VALUES (:text, NOW(), :file, :title)");
$stmt->bindParam(':text', $text);
$stmt->bindParam(':file', $file);
$stmt->bindParam(':title', $title);

 $stmt->execute();
```